# "Listing", "text" or "code" of program

Tags: differences, programming

What is the best way to name the program text before displaying it: "listing", "text" or "code"? I am inclined to believe that the word "listing" is the most official, the word "code" is slang, and the word "text" is neutral. But is it? Which word is best used on the web (in particular on the stackoverflow)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless it's the entire listing it's an "excerpt".

Comment: *Code* is not slang. It's both the technical term and the most accurate. (And you might list code or have a code listing, but *list* there is only acting as a verb or attributively.)  If you think that *code* is somehow informal or inappropriate for the field itself, you're really going to have to show why you think that, because it's an unusual interpretation.

Comment: @Hot Licks Thanks You! I understood.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Thanks You! I will use the "code" word.

Comment: The [**source code**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/source_code) is a human readable text listing of commands to be compiled or assembled into an executable computer program, and is unambiguous.

Comment: Why not look at a few similar pieces of software?

Comment: @Global Charm Why not ask?)